# Jquery, hiding and closing elements inside one element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a web app, where i faced a problem. The problem is, I have a span element, and inside that span element there are two more span elements. Simply, two children of the parent span element. One of the children is shown in the parent element, When someone click on the shown children element then, it will get the index value of that children and will hide it, and will show the next sibling. I have written some code, but it just work on one click, and when i click the next sibling when it has been shown, then the first sibling never get shown. Below is my code :

HTML

```js
<span class="ajlsst-wrap">

  <span class="ajls-save-sec ajls-save">
    <i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i>
    <span class="ajls-labe">Save</span>
  </span>

  <span class="ajls-save-sec ajls-saved">
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    <span class="ajls-labe">Saved</span>
  </span>

</span>
```

```js
$(".ajlsst-wrap").click(function(){

    var _index = $(this).find(".ajls-save-sec").index();

    console.log(_index);



   if(_index == 0){
        $(this).find(".ajls-save").hide();
        $(this).find(".ajls-saved").show();
    }
    else{
        $(this).find(".ajls-saved").hide();
        $(this).find(".ajls-save").show();
    }
    
   
})
```

> I also have a problem , that is, the index of first child is always detect not of the second one which is shown on click, i don`t know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it this way

```js
$(".ajls-save-sec").click(function(){
  
  $(this).hide().siblings().show()    
   
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="ajlsst-wrap">

  <span class="ajls-save-sec ajls-save">
    <i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i>
    <span class="ajls-labe">Save</span>
  </span>

  <span class="ajls-save-sec ajls-saved" style="display:none">
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    <span class="ajls-labe">Saved</span>
  </span>

</span>
```

Hope you get the concept.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use `$(".ajls-save-sec").click` instead of `$(".ajlsst-wrap").click`

You can use the simple next code

```js
$(".ajls-save-sec").click(function(){  // no need for $(".ajlsst-wrap")
    $(this).parent().find(".ajls-save-sec").show();  // show all spans
    $(this).hide();    // hide the clicked one
})
```

```css
.ajls-saved{
  display : none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="ajlsst-wrap">

  <span class="ajls-save-sec ajls-save">
    <i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i>
    <span class="ajls-labe">Save</span>
  </span>

  <span class="ajls-save-sec ajls-saved">
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    <span class="ajls-labe">Saved</span>
  </span>

</span>
<span class="ajlsst-wrap">

  <span class="ajls-save-sec ajls-save">
    <i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i>
    <span class="ajls-labe">Save</span>
  </span>

  <span class="ajls-save-sec ajls-saved">
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    <span class="ajls-labe">Saved</span>
  </span>

</span>
<span class="ajlsst-wrap">

  <span class="ajls-save-sec ajls-save">
    <i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i>
    <span class="ajls-labe">Save</span>
  </span>

  <span class="ajls-save-sec ajls-saved">
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    <span class="ajls-labe">Saved</span>
  </span>

</span>
```

Comment: But that doesn`t work when i have multiple divs, with same class name. I propagate those li